# Printing out an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an Arraylist here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person P1 = new Person("Nathen", 144.5, 55.1);
    Person P2 = new Person("Jamie", 133, 60);
    Person P3 = new Person("Tom", 134, 65);
    Person P4 = new Person("Lavi", 170, 70);

    ArrayList<String> Person = new ArrayList<String>();{
        Person.add(P1.getCategory());
        Person.add(P2.getCategory());
        Person.add(P3.getCategory());
        Person.add(P4.getCategory());
    }

    System.out.println(Person);
}
```

How can I get the program to print out the `Arraylist` one row at a time instead of the one big row I have now.

Comment: Have you read about for loops? what does google tell you...

Comment: I would also refrain from having a variable with the same name and case as a class name. At the very least that name doesn't make a great deal of sense - the collective noun is 'people'.

Comment: @JonK and since it's actually a list of categories, it should be named `categories`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use for-each loop

```
for(String str : Person){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: such informative answer which indeed deserve +1 for many times. lol

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should follow the [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and therefore you should change the variable `Person` to `person`, or a better name since it's a list of category like `categories`.

Second, coming to your request, a part the loop through each item option, you have 2 others way to print it the `person` list out.

- You can use the `Arrays.toString` method by passing the corresponding array of the `person` list. This is how you can write it:

  `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(person.toArray()));`

  Output: `[Nathen, Jamie, Tom, Lavi]`
- In case you are using/moved to Java 8+, you can use stream. This is how you can achieve it:

  `person.stream().forEach(System.out::println);`

  Output:

  `Nathen
  Jamie
  Tom
  Lavi`